# Printing jetty output to Eclipse console window

Tags: eclipse-plugin, jetty, embedded-jetty

I am developing an Eclipse plugin that includes starting an embedded jetty server, i.e.

```java
Server jetty = new Server(8080);
WebAppContext webapp = new WebAppContext("webapp", "/webapp");
webapp.setWar("path/to/webapp);
jetty.setHandler(webapp);
jetty.start();
Program.launch("http://localhost:8080/webapp");
```

I would like to see jetty's output in the console window of the Eclipse that contains my plugin. Instead jetty's output appears in Eclipse from that I am developing the plugin.

Answer (score 2):

Look into the Logging framework of Jetty.

Start by creating a custom [`org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Logger`](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/util/log/Logger.html) that can write to the Eclipse console window of your choice.

Example Implementations:

- The default [StrErrLog.java](http://git.eclipse.org/c/jetty/org.eclipse.jetty.project.git/tree/jetty-util/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/util/log/StdErrLog.java?id=jetty-9.0.2.v20130417) used by Jetty itself.
- The [SLf4jLog.java](http://git.eclipse.org/c/jetty/org.eclipse.jetty.project.git/tree/jetty-util/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/util/log/Slf4jLog.java?id=jetty-9.0.2.v20130417) for using slf4j logging with Jetty.
- The [JavaUtilLog.java](http://git.eclipse.org/c/jetty/org.eclipse.jetty.project.git/tree/jetty-util/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/util/log/JavaUtilLog.java?id=jetty-9.0.2.v20130417) for using java.util.logging with Jetty.

Then, before you instantiate any Jetty classes, call [`org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Log.setLog(Logger log)`](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/util/log/Log.html#setLog%28org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Logger%29) to set the underlying Logging framework that Jetty uses to your custom Logger implementation.

Good luck

Comment: Thank you for your starting points. Using your approach it seems I cannot manage to have several console windows -- each for every `Server` instance -- as the logger is being set globally for all ?`Server` instances. Do you see a chance to open a new console window for every `Server` instance? I could make use of a `JavaLaunchDelegate` to run jetty in a new JVM and have its output being printed into a separate console log. But I would like to avoid it.

Comment: Then leave the logging at StdErrLog, and capture/route the System.err to route to a specific console window.